# Mac OSX 10.6.4 - postinstall/postflight scripts fine in single pkgs but not in metapkgs

Tags: macos, packagemaker

I'm new to Mac OSX dev, and I'm having trouble with building a metapackage.

I have 7 pkgs which I want to wrap up into a metapkg.

When I executing each package separately everything works as expected, all scripts run etc.

However, when the same packages run as part of a metapackage, none of the scripts execute. The scripts are all postinstall or postflight.

I've tried using Iceberg in place of PackageMaker but get the same result.

Is there something I'm missing?

I'm tearing my hair out!

Thanks in advance,

Mark.